# UIImagePickerController add text to image

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to capture an image or video using the camera in iOS and add some text to a black bar overlayed at the bottom of the image.

I'm trying to get the text from a user input and save the image with the text and rectangle at the bottom of the image:

[image]

How would I go about this?

I currently have this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];

if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeImage]) {
    // A photo was taken/selected!
    self.image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    if (self.imagePicker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {
        // Save the image!
         UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.image, nil, nil, nil);
    }
}
else {
    // A video was taken/selected!
    self.videoFilePath = (__bridge NSString *)([[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path]);
    if (self.imagePicker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera) {

        // Save the video!
         if (UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(self.videoFilePath)) {
             UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(self.videoFilePath, nil, nil, nil);
         }
    }
}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; }
```

What would be the best way of going about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a UIView over the UIImageView with black (with alpha to be 0.5) background and on this UIView you can add a UILabel with your text.

Comment: I don't think so this way helps him to store image with text on it.

Comment: No it will just add text on imageview not  on image

Comment: I'm trying to get the text from a user input and save the image with the text and rectangle at the bottom of the image. Now may be he wants to save the image with its text OR image with text on it.

Comment: I'd like the image saved in the image library with the text on it if it is possible. So it looks like the attached image when its in the photo library

Answer (score 0):

I'd say have the user do an input using a UIAlertView

here's a sample

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@"Title Here"
                      message:@"message"
                      delegate:self
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" // or nil
                      otherButtonTitles:@"Ok",
                      nil];

alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
[alert show];
```

that shows that an alert will appear with a text box in it. Since we set self to delegate, you have to call that delegate as such

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];
if ([title isEqualToString:@"Ok"]) {
    NSString *alertText = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text;
    // create UILabel here and set the text as advised in answer above
    // example with global UILabel *overlayLabel;
    self.overlayLabel.text = alertText;
    // self.overlayLabel.font = [UIFont ...];
}
}
```

This is essentially what apple does. Go to the music app, and hit the "new playlist" and you'll see it in action

hope this helps!

Comment: he wants to save the image with text. like we add text in paint etc

Comment: I am saying use @Ashu answer, as adding a UIView with a label, and then using this method for the text the user wants to enter on the image